# Database with no authentication

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB install on the server of one of my clients.

An application I have no control on is using one single Mongo database without authentication.

Basically I would like that every new database requires authentication, but the previous one needs to be accessed without using credentials.

I managed to enable authentication successfully, but now the previous database requires authentication.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just to confirm, you have no way of changing any application code etc at all correct? or is that a possibility, IE. an application config that points to 2 mongodb services, one w/ authentication enabled, and the other without?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not possible. MongoDB authentication is on/off per instance. You could try splitting that one database out into its own instance?